# dropdown abierto en plantuml

Tags: wireframe, plantuml

De momento tengo este diagrama

[image: login con cuadro desplegable cerrado]

lo generé con el siguiente código

```
@startsalt
{#
  Login    | ^ Seleccione el usuario ^
  Password | "****     "
  [Cancel] | [  OK   ]
}
@endsalt
```

¿Cómo puedo poner el dropdown abierto?

Ya intenté poniendo saltos de línea, tablas dentro del dropdown, etc pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traducido por Google translate: Lamento no hablar español (utilicé Google para traducir su pregunta) ya que podía entender la pregunta en parte (la pregunta en inglés sobre Stack Overflow hubiera sido mejor para mí).

Qué tal si:

```
@startsalt
{
  Login | ^ Seleccione el usuario ^ name1 ^ name2 ^
  Password | "****     "
  [Cancel] | [  OK   ]
}
@endsalt
```

[image: dropdown abierto con dos opciones]